# Vector geometry

Tags: geometry

Let $V = 25i  + 15j  - 30k$ . What angles does this vector make with the $x, y$, and $z$ axes?

I'm a bit confused on how I should approach this problem. I am trying to find, $\theta_x$, $\theta_y$ and $\theta_z$. Can anyone lend a hand?

Answer (score 2):

We know that $a.b=|a||b|\cos \theta$ theta being the acute angle between them.

Now you take take the unit vector in each direction of x,y,z and find the angle between this and the unit vector.

between this vector and the unit vector in the x direction the angle will be

$(1i).(25i+15j-30 k)=25 +0+0$

So we have $\displaystyle \cos \theta_x=\frac{25}{\sqrt{1}.\sqrt{25^2+15^2+(-30)^2}}$

$\theta_x=\arccos{\frac{25}{\sqrt{1}.\sqrt{25^2+15^2+(-30)^2}}}$

Geometry : We know that the dot product of two vectors is the projection of one vector onto the unit vector of the other.So a projection can only be defined with the angle between the two vectors thus the $\cos \theta$ term comes.

Like wise for other cases.

Comment: Ok but that isn't telling me much. I'm still confused on how the actual geometry of these vectors needs to be drawn. Did you mean dot product or (a,b)?

Comment: Yes the dot product @JohnCarpenter

Comment: Well that leads me to 5/sqrt(70) but when I type that in for the compnent for cos(theta x) it is not correct.

Comment: I couldnt get you @JohnCarpenter.

Comment: Well if do the calculation for finding cos theta x I take my answer and plug it in but my computer says it is wrong.

Comment: I cant understand why it does so. I think this is the correct answer. The answer is also clear from the explanation of the dot product.

Comment: Yeah I still am not getting any of the right answers. Does anybody want to explain how to get to each theta?

Comment: Now is the answer correct @JohnCarpenter